# Cpanel is unable to load login page

Tags: cpanel, ftp

I am a trying to load Cpanel login page. Below is link of Cpanel login page:

```
http://sale.coupsoft.com:2082
```

I am an unable to open the following page using my IP address. Chrome loader is running but it's not displaying any data. (Even text field and logo of Cpanel).  I checked in cpanel that there is no any IP address blocked.

I tried FileZilla and even Filezilla is unable to log me in. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact your web host for support

Answer (score 2):

I've made few edits to your question.

You need to contact your support. It can be large variety why you can't access your cpanel.

Mostly there's a wrong credentials or you are trying to access on wrong address.

Firstly, try with them, and I'm sure that everything would be solved for you.